# Writing a test predicate to see if all duplicates have been removed from a list

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I am trying to write a predicate `testRemove/1` whose input is a list and which tests whether a predicate `removeDups/2` indeed removes any duplicates but retains all the elements of a list. Here is my code for the `removeDups/1` predicate. I'm trying to create the test for it

```
%if H is in the accumulator, it does nothing and processes the tail. 

%If H isn't a member of the accumulator, append H to it and then process the tail.

removeDups(List, Set):- removeDupsHelp(List, [], Set).

removeDupsHelp([], Acc, Acc).

removeDupsHelp([H|T], Acc, Set):-member(H, Acc),removeDupsHelp(T, Acc, Set).

removeDupsHelp([H|T], Acc, Set):- removeDupsHelp(T,[H|Acc], Set).
```

Comment: Start with how you want `testRemove/1` to be defined conceptually: *`testRemove(L)` succeeds if...* What would you say after the *if*?

Comment: `removeDups(List, Set).` followed by `removeDupsHelp(List, [], Set).` can't be right!

Comment: Code has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

Ask answered in your previous question we know `sort/2` predicate remove duplicates so use `sort(Your_List,Sorted_List)` and check if `Sorted_List` is has same elements as `Set` from your predicate.